# «Улетай в гордый вызов орла»

Tags: значение-слов

В песне «Улетай» группы «Калинов мост» есть слова:

> Улетай  — первым проблеском солнца...
>   **Улетай — в гордый вызов орла...**
>   Брось в огонь шелест в грубых ладонях,
>   Не догнать окриком тебя.

Интересно, как нужно (можно?) понимать выделенную фразу? Что значит «улетай *в гордый **вызов*** орла»?

Comment: Aer, в этой песне почти все фразы — гордые вызовы, так что просто улетайте, а не ходите вокруг с томиком Розенталя в руках.

Comment: @М_Г с Розенталем не хожу, даже в кабинете не держу; улетать, позвольте, не буду — все-таки надо будет нового модератора выбирать...

Comment: Я имел в виду, что Вы полетаете и вернетесь, нельзя оставлять сайт без такого хорошего модератора!

Answer (score 1):

Орёл гордо, как принято у поэтов, кружит высоко в небе, как бы бросая вызов человеку:" Способен ли ты достичь моих высот?!"  Именно в этот вызов и предлагается улететь герою песни,  я полагаю.

Comment: А почему вызов -- это то, ___во___ что можно улететь? )

Comment: Здесь вызов - поэтический образ, всеобъемлещая высота, расширяющая приземленное сознание человека.

Answer (score 1):

Я готов понять эту фразу только в случае, если в предыдущем стихе (не знаю, есть ли он) авторами *явно* указано место назначения перелёта (город, край, пламень, опасное дупло и т. п.), к которому грамматически подходит употреблённый далее предлог "в" (это не может быть "утёс" и пр.) и которое здесь поименовано "вызовом".

Comment: Беда в том, что с этих слов песня начинается